# fade in/out with AVAudioEngine

Tags: avaudioengine

My app dynamically adds and removes nodes feeding the `mainMixerNode`. When this happens, I hear a click or pop because the volume isn't faded.

**How can I achieve smooth transitions when making connections?** Do I need to implement the fade myself within my AudioUnit or can AVAudioEngine handle it more elegantly?

Answer (score 2):

I have a fade out in my app without touching the AudioUnit (code is below).
You can adapt this to do a fade in as well.

Note that I assign the timer to a member var so I can invalidate it at other points (`viewWillDisappear`, `delloc`, etc.). I was worried that it wouldn't sound smooth, but I tried it and it works fine.

```
- (void)fadeOutAudioWithDuration:(double)duration {
    double timerInterval = 0.1;
    NSNumber *volumeInterval = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(timerInterval / duration)];
    self.fadeOutTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timerInterval target:self selector:@selector(fadeOutTimerDidFire:) userInfo:volumeInterval repeats:YES];
}

- (void)fadeOutTimerDidFire:(NSTimer *)timer {
    float volumeInterval = ((NSNumber *)timer.userInfo).floatValue;
    float currentVolume = self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.outputVolume;
    float newValue = MAX(currentVolume - volumeInterval, 0.0f);
    self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.outputVolume = newValue;
    if (newValue == 0.0f) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```